# Why is the parent's constructor being called

Tags: php, inheritance, constructor, spl-autoload-register

I have the simplest bit of code :

**Interface**

```
interface iCrudRepository{
    public function Create($id);
    public function Read($id);
    public function Update($id);
    public function Delete($id);
}
```

**Parent**

```
class Repository
{
   function __construct()
   {
     echo "SHOULD NOT BE CALLED AUTOMATICALLY";
   }
}
```

**Class**

```
require_once(__DIR__.'/../injection/bootstrap.php');

class Admin extends Repository implements iCrudRepository
{
  function Create($id)
  {
  }

  function Read($id)
  {
  }

  function Update($id)
  {
  }

  function Delete($id)
  {
  }
}

$admin = new Admin();
$admin->Create("Something");
```

The `bootstrap` class autoloads my classes via the `spl_autoload_register` function. Since in the `Admin` class I don't call the parent constructor, it shouldn't execute what is in the parent's constructor right?

**The Output**

```
SHOULD NOT BE CALLED AUTOMATICALLY
```

Probably missing something obvious here but can't quite figure out why it is called.

Comment: Constructors are automatically called, once you call `new` on the class that `extend`s the parent class. You can overload that method by putting `public function __construct(){}`, in the inheriting class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) state:

> Parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child class
>   defines a constructor.

So you have to do this in order to prevent what you are seeing:

```
class Admin extends Repository implements iCrudRepository
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }
  function Create($id)
  {
  }

  function Read($id)
  {
  }

  function Update($id)
  {
  }

  function Delete($id)
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. simple enough although it feels kind of counter intuitive.. thanks ^^.

Comment: @phadaphunk not a problem. I think this happens in Java as well, not sure about other languages though.